# What was this movie involving girls who turned into monsters?

Tags: story-identification, horror

Okay this has been bothering me for years. When I was younger, I remember going to the movie store and seeing this movie with a group of girls on the cover, maybe 3? And they were really pretty on the cover, but on the back, it showed that they turned into these nasty creatures — I think one may have even had spots on her, like animals spots but not with fur — they were all covered in skin. They were bald and ugly when they changed and they killed people. On the back of the case, I think one of the creatures was getting ready to eat a dude or something. I don't think it was a very popular movie because I've been searching for years and cannot find it. I think it was set between 90s to early 2000s based on the style on the front cover.

The details I gave are obviously not great but I will take any suggestions, and I know it's one of those things that once I see it again I will remember. It has just been forever and it's been on my mind this whole time.

Comment: So what was the movie about? You said you went to the movie with 3 girls who turned into monsters. That sounds like a bad evening :(.

Comment: @RyanJ - Or a very good evening, depending on how *freaky* you wanna get.

Comment: Take a look at the list at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if you can fill in any more details. I modified your question a little to try to make things clearer.

Comment: So I'm just gonna put it out there: Sorority Babes and the Slimeball Bowl-A-Rama.

Answer (score 3):

There is not much to go on, but it does remind me of the following title: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091847/ The Revenge of the Living Dead Girls (1987)

> I think one may have even had spots on her, like animals spots but not with fur — they were all covered in skin. They were bald and ugly when they changed and they killed people

I don't remember them being bald, but they sure are ugly:
[image: TRotLDG1]

> I think one of the creatures was getting ready to eat a dude or something.

Might have been this scene?

[image: TRotLDG2]

> I think it was set between 90s to early 2000s based on the style on the front cover.

It's a bit older, it's from 1987, but close..

It also had an alternate ending. After it they asked the audiance to keep quiet about it... I still am.
But it's probably the best part of the movie, which isn't hard :)

Answer (score 3):

This story is a bit like [Ginger Snaps](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0210070/) (2000). One front cover has three faces. There are two sisters in the movie. One turns into a werewolf, the second becomes infected. There is a sequel, [Ginger Snaps 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0353489/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

**Cover:**

[image]

**Ugly phase:**

[image]

Reference:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0210070/

Comment: There is also a prequel: Ginger Snaps Back, the beginning. Set in 1815. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365265/